# Test with same action but different contexts

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, browser-automation

I'm working in a company as a QA intern, we do end to end testing with browser automation.

We have lots of tests scenarios that looks like that : (we use cucumber)

```
Given I am logged in
When I go to my address book
Then I can see my contacts
```

but recently we had few bugs depending on what kind of account we are logged in so in order to tests this edges case I'm thinking of doing something like that:

```
Given I am logged in as with in as a project manager
When I go to my address book
Then I can see my contacts
```

And do that for every kind of account (project manager, commercial, etc ...)

But I'm asking about the interest of doing that .. For every user the outcome should be the same, they should all see their contacts. (even if due to a bug it was not the case)
if I start doing that way, I would be legit to have test like

```
Given I am logged in with a german account
```

and same with french, english etc...

but it would lead to an explosion of the number of tests

So do you guys test those edge case ?
If yes, how to do it efficiently ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cucumber sceanrio examples like below .

Scenario Outline:  
Given I am logged in as `"<userAccount>"` . 
When I go to my address book . 
Then I can see my contacts

Examples:  
|userAccount| . 
|ABC| . 
|XYZ| .

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't test for this in an integration test. Exactly because it leads to an explosion of test cases. Instead you re-engineer the system in such a way that you can test this at a lower level and still have confidence that the edge case is covered.

One way to do this would be to create "fake" countries. Each with either a single interesting attribute or a combination of interesting attributes.